# If condition , doesn't code execute code properly

Tags: c++, mfc

This code takes a string from a dialog box , and compares it to data in a list,and if succesfull sets the selection on the element from list .
The problem i am having is with the if , it works if i only search the first element , if i try to search any other , it just ignore the if condition and goes till the end o the list .

```
void CMFC1Dlg::OnBnClickedButton6()
{ 
    CString variable;
    cautare.GetWindowTextA(variable);
    variable = variable.MakeLower(); 

    if(variable!="")
    {
        list<Contact*>::iterator seek;
        bool flag = TRUE;
        int i = 0 ;
        while(flag)
        {
             seek = agenda.first_element();

                if( ((CString)((*seek)->getLastName().c_str())).MakeLower() == variable  || 
                    ((CString)((*seek)->getFirstName().c_str())).MakeLower() == variable || 
                    ((CString)((*seek)->getFirstAndLastName().c_str())).MakeLower() == variable ||
                    ((CString)((*seek)->getLastAndFirstName().c_str())).MakeLower() == variable)
                {
                    contactsVariable.SetCurSel(i);
                    this->OnLbnSelchangeList1();
                    flag=FALSE;
                }

                advance(seek,i);
                i++;
                if (i == agenda.list_size())
                {
                    flag = FALSE;
                }

        }
    }
    else
        MessageBox("No text on input ", "Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);

    cautare.SetFocus();
    cautare.SetWindowTextA("");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only ever comparing the first element move `advance(seek,i);` like this:

```
 while(flag)
 {
     seek = agenda.first_element();
     advance(seek,i);
     ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You are setting `seek = agenda.first_element();` at the beginning of every iteration of the while loop. Move that statement outside the loop and it should work.

**EDIT**: You would also need to change the seek call to only seek 1, rather than i, since you're no longer throwing out the result of the previous seeks.

Answer (score 2):

You should move `seek = agenda.first_element();` out of the while loop.

Comment: No , i need seek to be set to first element each time , so that when i advance , i get to the "i " element in the list

Comment: If he does that the advance method would result in very weird behavior.

Comment: @Karudi:  `advance(seek,i); i++;` should go before the `if()` then.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are iterating over a list of elements, why not use the `begin()` and `end()` method of the associated list. So you can iterate over each element and don't need to advance the iterator in each loop.

The code could look like this

```
list<Contract*>::iterator seek = agenda.begin();
while (flag && (seek != agenda.end())) {
    // do the comparison
    seek++;
}
```